# Cant ping wan IP programatically in android

Tags: android

I'm working with connecting and retrieving data from IP in android. To check whether IP is online before retrieving data, I'm pinging IP using InetAddress.getByName(hostName).isReachable(20000). It's working fine for LAN, But for WAN, getting timeOut. 
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: please post your code here...

Comment: try {
boolean b = InetAddress.getByName(hostname).isReachable(20000);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
       boolean b = InetAddress.getByName(hostname).isReachable(40000);
     } 
  catch (Exception e) 
   {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
```

you have to add this 20000 milllisecod to 40000 milliseconds..
so this is paramter if you not reach your network at 20000 then you got timeout..

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: Tried upto 60000 millisec. Its working fine for lanIP, but not working for wanIP